# SQL LIKE REGEXP Matching Single Value and Comma'd String

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am working on a database that has been made in a terrible way. I have to find an ID in a comma'd column.

The column values could be:

- 6154
- 5145,6154,4562
- 161545

My query is:

```
SELECT resource_id,filename,id FROM image WHERE other_vendors = '".$vendor_id."'
```

`$vendor_id` will be 6154

Now how do I match with a LIKE REGULAR EXPRESSION in a SQL QUERY where I get all the values which have a 6154 or 6154 in a comma'd string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use build in function [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), which search string in comma separated list:

```
SELECT resource_id,filename,id FROM image WHERE find_in_set('6154',other_vendors)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the easiest method:

```
SELECT resource_id,filename,id FROM image WHERE (','+other_vendors +',') like '%,$vendor_id,%'
```

Comment: I would use this approach too, this is the only answer that won't match `161545`.

Comment: If an id could be a substring of a comma seperated list (that's kind of an unusual behavior) just remove all the commas from the query, which would yield only `other_vendors LIKE '%$vendor_id%'`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT resource_id,filename,id FROM image WHERE other_vendors REGEXP '.*(6154){1}.*'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT resource_id,filename,id FROM image WHERE other_vendors = '%6154%'
```